# How to easily add cropped screenshot to self-hosted Wordpress as hosted image?

Tags: php, wordpress, firefox

I do a lot of tutorials using Wordpress. The main characteristic thing is that every tutorial has a lot of screenshots. Not just whole screen shots, but fragments of screen important for explained part of tutorial. In my work i do mostly website parts screenshots.

I usually do it like this:
- press PRINT SCREEN
- open Irfan View
- paste whole screen capture
- crop part i need
- save it do disc of my computer
- click "add image" in wordpress
- choose the image from disc
- voila, one image is added to post

And when i write 1 tutorial post i do it like 20-30 times...
So my problem is that it takes like "A LOT" of time.

And search some plugins to help me with this work. I use Firefox, but have also Chrome and Opera. I've found "Light Shot" plugin for Firefox. It' basically gives you option to select part of webpage and save it to it's website or clipboard. But unfortunately you can not embedd the image from their server in wordpress.

So i pasted clipboard images to blog post. But when i do this images are embedded as inline images. It worked for short tutorials. But when i saved tutorial with 5 images Wordpress cut it in half and saved only half of my post.

And even if i would fix it somehow i dont want to have inline images, because it would kill my server performance and you can't share the image in other posts.

So i thought i ask you guys if you know any solution to make screengrabbing to Wordpress easier. Maybe there is ready solution I didn't know before.

UPDATE:
Light Shot can take cropped screenshot to clipboard. So what i would need now is a extension or application that can upload image from clipboard to Wordpress gallery. Do you know any?

Comment: I would love to see this too. Personally I have used SnagIt and it is very good. This blog post talks about autoexport to Wordpress. Maybe you can give it a try. http://www.attacat.co.uk/brain/add-screenshots-to-wordpress-org#axzz1hwPOygFu

Comment: Thanks. Ive tested SnagIt. It creates new blog post and does not make putting image into actual post easier. So it's off the table for me. iClippy is nice but i don't like the idea of sidebar all the time on screen. PicturePaste looks nice and for 10 dollars you can host in on your FTP server, crops so ye... thats the solution. Place answer pls.

Comment: It's not perfect but still... it's something :)

Comment: Well... it does not work properly. When i paste image into Wordpress i get: 椼杭猠捲∽瑨灴⼺瀯㉰献⸳浡穡湯睡⹳潣⽭ㅡ㠱搴㙢㈶昷㌴愷戯㜵㙡愷㔸㌷㑡㉣㡤敦挰〹㔹㡦㡢敥⹦灪≧愠瑬∽浩条≥眠摩桴∽㐱∸栠楥桧㵴㤢∸戠牯敤㵲〢⼢>. Nice huh?

Comment: Bummer. I really hope you get a better solution. Maybe we should write one and be millionaires?

Comment: Have you tried using PhotoBucket instead? Firefox has an addon that lets you right click an image and upload it to PB. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/photobucket-uploader/ Just load the image in Firefox after cropping and saving it.

Comment: @mrtsherman maybe??? I think how many other people have this problem....

Comment: well.. as for now not so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best solution i have found is SPGrab

Answer (score 1):

There are a few services that do this for you, such as:

http://www.websnapr.com/

Comment: It captures whole page and what i need is to crop part of this.

Comment: Once you have the image, you can use this. You'll have to know WHERE to crop it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Answer (score 0):

This site lists three options:

1. [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) with autoexport - images go into a new post. $50
2. http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html
3. [PicturePaste](http://picturepaste.com/) - Free for 50 pictures. $10 if you host on your own server. $30 to use their servers.

http://www.attacat.co.uk/brain/add-screenshots-to-wordpress-org#axzz1hwPOygFu

Answer (score 0):

there was one ff extension that was very promising - it seems to have dissapeared :(

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screen-grab-to-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: Light Shot can take cropped screenshot to clipboard. So what i would need now is a extension or application that can upload image from clipboard to Wordpress gallery. Do you know any?

There is now a free Wordpress plugin called [Image Clipboard](http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-clipboard/). It allows you to paste images from the clipboard directly into Wordpress posts using Ctrl-V.

I use it in combination with [LightScreen](http://lightscreen.sourceforge.net/), which is a screen-grabbing tool that supports capturing arbitrary regions of the screen.